# How to register a sensor listener inside a button's onClick method?

Tags: android, button, overriding, listener, accelerometer

I have an application in which I want to start a listener for the accelerometer when a button is clicked, so I tried this way:

```
private SensorManager sensorManager;

@Override
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.storing_act);

    Button start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startl);

    start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            sensorManager=(SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
            sensorManager.registerListener(this, 
                    sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
                    SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        }
    });
```

but it appears a message with

> "The method registerListener(SensorEventListener, Sensor, int) in the type SensorManager is not applicable for the arguments (new View.OnClickListener(){}, Sensor, int)"

Is there a way to solve it easy? Do I have to override any other method? Thanks

Comment: instead of this you should pass YouActivityName.this

Comment: You are trying to register a `View` listener to the sensor manager which expects a [SensorEventListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEventListener.html), as the error tells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `MyActivity.this` because `this` refers to `OnClickListener` and the `registerListener` method is expecting `SensorEventListener`.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.storing_act);

        Button start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startl);

        start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                sensorManager=(SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
                sensorManager.registerListener(MyActivity.this, 
                        sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
                        SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
            }
        });
}
```